# getting error during distcp between two different version of hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I am using distcp between hadoop 0.20 and hadoop 2.2.0 versions.I am getting error during data transfer  between these clusters using below distcp command:
hadoop distcp  -skipcrccheck -update

getting below error:
HTTP_OK expected, received 400

Solutions will be appreciated.